# gpgpu_util.bindVertexProgramAttributeStreams error on tfjs qna/BERT model

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, bert-language-model

i got the following "hello world" example from this `[tensorflow YouTube tutorial][1]`

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/qna"></script>
<script>
  /* global qna */
  const searchText = 'We believe cats are the real stars of YouTube.'
  const question = 'What is important to YouTube?'
    
  qna.load().then(model => {
    model.findAnswers(question, searchText).then(answers => {
            console.log('Answers:', answers)
        })
  })
  
</script>
```

unlike the video's claim, this returns an empty array after throwing the following error in the console:

```
Assertion failed: gpgpu_util.bindVertexProgramAttributeStreams not fully successful.
```

I can't seem to find anything on this particular error online, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this error after updating `@tensorflow/tfjs` from `4.1.0` to `4.2.0`.

Previously I had `@tensorflow/tfjs-node` at `4.2.0` and `@tensorflow/tfjs` at `4.1.0`.

Comment: i think the cdn for `@tensorflow/tfjs` returns the latest version. in any case i just checked by logging tf.version and it's `4.2.0` but still getting the same error :(